# linux cp file at the same directory but do not want cd to that directory

Tags: linux, cp

what i do

```
$ cp /etc/libvirt/qemu/centos7.8.xml{,123.xml}
```

what happend

```
$ ls /etc/libvirt/qemu/
centos7.8.xml centos7.8.xml123.xml
```

but what i want is

```
$ ls /etc/libvirt/qemu/
centos7.8.xml 123.xml
```

i don't want to use the follow , write /etc/libvirt/qemu twice:

```
$ cp /etc/libvirt/qemu/centos7.8.xml /etc/libvirt/qemu/123.xml
```

and i know what {,_backup} mean.

any way?

like follow ? no such format

```
cp /etc/libvirt/qemu/centos7.8.xml{123.xml}
```

Comment: So `cp /etc/libvirt/qemu/{centos7.8.xml,123.xml}` ?? Do you understand how understand how `{x,y,z}` works?

Comment: KamilCuk's solution to properly use brace expansion is probably what you want, but there are many ways to do this. eg  `d=/etc/libvirt/qemu; cp $d/centos7.8.xml $d/123.xml` and `(cd /p/a/t/h; cp centos7.8.xml 123.xml)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash extension [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) you can do the following:

```
cp /etc/libvirt/qemu/{centos7.8.xml,123.xml}
```

or even:

```
cp /etc/libvirt/qemu/{centos7.8,123}.xml
```